# UIWebView not displaying URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

Pretty easy enough problem, but It's driving me crazy. I connected my uiwebview to the .h and called it myWebView. then in the viewdidLoad, i did this:

```
 NSString *urlString = @"www.google.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[myWebView loadRequest:request];
```

But when I run the app I just see a blank screen...

I don't know what's going on.

All help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `urlstring` isn't well-formed (for your intent)

Use `http://www.google.com/`

Technically `www.google.com` is a valid URL (according to things like RFC [1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) and [3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)), but since it lacks the scheme (the `http` part), the `UIWebView` doesn't quite know what to do with it.

Comment: Ah, giving it a go at the moment

Comment: Thanks for the easy fix! I can accept answers in 11 minutes